# Parameter "MoveX" (and "MoveY") does not exist

Tags: unity, 2d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed;

    public Animator anim;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") > 0.5f ||        
        Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < - 0.5f) {
            transform.Translate (new Vector3  
        (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f));
        }

        if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical") < -0.5f) {
            transform.Translate (new Vector3 (0f, Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f));
        }

        anim.SetFloat("MoxeX", Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal"));
        anim.SetFloat("MoxeY", Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical"));

        }
    }
```

I an trying to run this with a basic 2D animation in unity personal and I keep getting Warning! - 
Parameter "MoveX" does not exist 
and Parameter "MoveY" does not exist 
but it is clearly in the animator as a float.

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of your animator window? Are you sure MoveX and MoveY are spellwd the same way as in the animator?

Comment: In your code, you are passing "MoxeX" and "MoxeY" not "MoveX" or "MoveY"

Answer (score 1):

You typoed. `MoxeX` instead of `MoveX`, and  `MoxeY` instead of `MoveY`